# Am I using async C# correctly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following bit of code the calls out to two different command line components (each wrapped in their own Task)

```
public async Task<FileInfo> RasterizeAllPdfs(IEnumerable<Uri> targetUris, FileInfo destination = null)
{
    // rasterize uris to files in the rasterizedOutput directory
    await rasterize(rasterizedOutput.Value, targetUris); 
    // concatenate all pdfs in this directory
    return await concatenatePdfs(rasterizedOutput.Value.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf"), destination);
}
```

What I would like is for the method to return a task immediately and for the returned task to become resolved once the task returned by concatentatePdfs finishes running.

It *seems* to work correctly (as in it's returning correct output) but I'm not 100% sure that I'm using the async and await keywords properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `async`/`await` absolutely correctly, that's how they were supposed to be used.

Please note that from this code it's hard to tell whether the method will return the `Task` immediately, since it will be waiting synchronously for `rasterize` method to return the `Task`, and thus the answer depends on the implementation of `rasterize`.

As a side note - you are using implicit dependency here (first method prepares files in folder, and second method enumerates all pdf files there). I would prefer explicit dependency: `rasterize` to return a collection of FileInfo objects consumed by the `concatenatePdfs` method.

Comment: Thanks, this is all private to a class so I'm not terribly concerned about explicit vs implicit dependencies. I think I might want to change what I'm doing though. I want the second method to be a continuation of the first completing successfully but I don't want to block the thread while this happens (hence return immediately). Do I have to use `ContinueWith()` in that case? Is that correct? Basically if this was jQuery deferreds I would want to return `firstMethodDeferred.pipe(secondMethod)`.

Comment: `await` does exactly that. You can think of it as "the code after await will execute after the awaiting task completes". It's implemented slightly differently to `ContinueWith`, but idea is the same

Comment: So I'm not quite clear how to combine the two, simply placing the second line into a `ContinueWith` block doesn't work because now my return is `Task<Task<FileInfo>>` I basically have two tasks that I want to combine to run in sequence

Comment: And about "I don't want to block the thread while this happens" - it will not block the thread if `rasterize` doesn't do heavy things synchronously, that is before the first await (assuming you're using awaits there as well). Just for you to understand: the first part of the method till first `await` is executed synchronously, and will continue to run synchronously in case when task being awaited is already completed at the time of awaiting.

Comment: "So I'm not quite clear..." - you don't need `ContinueWith` here, your current code will run methods in sequence